# Do I have to explicitly close session before redirecting to another page?

Tags: php, session, redirect

Do I have to explicitly close session before redirecting to another page?

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['login']))
    $login = $_SESSION['login'];
else {
    // is session_write_close() necessary here?
    header('Location: /login');
    exit();
}
```

---

Is there any way to tell PHP to close the session, but also to not bother saving session data? (Something like `session_discard_close()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very hard to answer this anymore fully than "no".

However, if you read the PHP manual page for [session_write_close](http://www.php.net/session_write_close) you'll see that it states:

> Session data is usually stored after
>   your script terminated without the
>   need to call session_write_close(),
>   but as session data is locked to
>   prevent concurrent writes only one
>   script may operate on a session at any
>   time. When using framesets together
>   with sessions you will experience the
>   frames loading one by one due to this
>   locking. You can reduce the time
>   needed to load all the frames by
>   ending the session as soon as all
>   changes to session variables are done.

As such, in some edge cases the answer is "no, but it might be faster if you do".

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not necessary. The session will be automatically closed at the end of the request. From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php):

> Session data is usually stored after
>   your script terminated without the
>   need to call session_write_close(),
>   but as session data is locked to
>   prevent concurrent writes only one
>   script may operate on a session at any
>   time.